# Basic even or odd question. Complete the isLastEvenOdd function below

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Complete the isLastEvenOdd function below. The function should:

Take one input parameter, an array of numbers and return the string 'even' or 'odd' based on whether the last item in the array is even or odd.

I tried this:

```
function isLastEvenOdd(numArray) {
  if (numArray %2===0) {
    return 'even'
  } else {
    return 'odd'
  }
}
```

✗ it works for an even positive number

Error Failed [1, 2, 3, 4]: expected 'odd' to deeply equal 'even'

✓ it works for an odd negative number

Comment: Note that you'll be passed an array, not a number. Trying to do `numArray % 2` won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isLastEvenOdd(numArray) {
  if (numArray[numArray.length -1 ] %2===0) {
    return 'even'
  } else {
    return 'odd'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here try using this instead:

```
var arraylength = array.length;
if (array[arraylength - 1] % 2 == 0) {
  return 'even';
} else {
  return 'odd';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The numArray needs to look specifically at the last element.

Use numArray.length-1 as the index.

```js
function isLastEvenOdd(numArray) {
  return numArray[numArray.length - 1] % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
}


function fnProcess() {
  
  var arrTest = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 
  console.log(isLastEvenOdd(arrTest));

  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fnProcess()">Process</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function isLastEvenOdd(arr) {
    return 0 === arr.pop() % 2 ? "even" : "odd";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the number percent symbol on an array you should try this instead:

```
function isLastEvenOdd(myNumber) {
  if((myNumber % 2) === 0) {
    return 'even';
  } else {
    return 'odd';
  }
}
```